# How to use Lispworks comm package for SSL access in Postmodern instead of cl+ssl

Tags: ssl, lisp, common-lisp

On XP, I'd like to use Postmodern in Lispworks to use the database on
a server via SSL.

It looks like CL+SSL has a problem with setting up a unilateral SSL
connection. Lispworks works fine. Is there a way to get Postmodern to
use the socket set up by Lispworks instead of one by CL+SSL? Or is
there a version of CL+SSL which can make a unilateral connection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hack Postmodern to use Lispwork's SSL API instead of CL+SSL. This probably isn't too hard.

Comment: It probably isn't too hard, but after trying for quite a bit, I can say it's too hard for me.